# Finding non-closed subspace $M$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ such that $M\cap LM = \{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am too stupid to find a bounded operator $A : \ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ with *non-closed* range $M = \operatorname{ran}A$ such that $M\cap LM = \{0\}$, where $L$ is the left-shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. I think finding such should be easy with the help of an ONB $(e_n')$ of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, where $\langle e_n',e_m\rangle\neq 0$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$. But I do not have any such basis at hand. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to get non-closed range is with an injective compact operator. For instance, if we write $\{e_n\}$ for the canonical orthonormal basis, we can define 
$$
Ax=\sum_n\frac1n\,\langle x,e_n\rangle\,e_n.
$$
But this will fail the other requirement, so let's tweak our example: let
$$
Ax=\sum_n\frac1n\,\langle x,e_{2n}\rangle\,e_{2n}.
$$
Now $$M=\text{span}\,\{e_{2n}:\ n\in\mathbb N\},$$ and 
$$
LM=\text{span}\,\{e_{2n+1}:\ n\in\mathbb N\}.
$$
The intersection is clearly $\{0\}$.

Comment: It is not true that $M = \operatorname{span}\{e_{2n} : n\in\mathbb N\}$. The subspace $M$ is somewhere in between $\operatorname{span}\{e_{2n} : n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{e_{2n} : n\in\mathbb N\}$. However, your trick works perfect. Thanks so much! I indeed was too stupid.