# Finding dense subspace $M$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ such that $M\cap LM = \{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am looking for a bounded operator $A : \ell^2(\mathbb N)\to\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ with *dense* range $M = \operatorname{ran}A$ such that $M\cap LM = \{0\}$, where $L$ is the left-shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. I think finding such should be easy with the help of an ONB $(e_n')$ of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, where $\langle e_n',e_m\rangle\neq 0$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$. But I do not have any such basis at hand. Can anyone help me out?

Actually, I asked the question before without the density requirement ([Finding non-closed subspace $M$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ such that $M\cap LM = \{0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213557/finding-non-closed-subspace-m-in-ell2-mathbb-n-such-that-m-cap-lm-0)). Please excuse me.